# Trigger javascript event in WPF WebView2

Tags: javascript, wpf, webview

I'm trying to automate filling in a form on a webpage in WebView2.
I can fill the input-value on the page, but when I fill another  the value in the first box is cleared.
It seems from the DevTools Window that the website (when filling the form by hand) triggers a keydown-event. Than the value is saved.
I cannot seem to trigger an Javascript-event on the webpage through "ExecuteScriptAsync".
How can I raise an event through the WebView?

I tried this:

```
Await WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').click();") 'works!
Await WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').focus();") 'works!
Await WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').value = 'me@example.com';") 'works!
Await WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').setAttribute('value','me@example.com');") 'works!
Await WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').dispatchEvent(New Event('input', { 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true }));") 'nothing happens
Await WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').dispatchEvent(New Event('invalid', { 'bubbles: true, 'cancelable': true }));") 'nothing happens
Await WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').dispatchEvent(New Event('change', { 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true }));") 'nothing happens
Await WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').dispatchEvent(New KeyboardEvent('keydown', { keyCode: 'Tab', which: 9 }));") 'nothing happens
Await WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').dispatchEvent(New KeyboardEvent('keyup', { keyCode: 'Tab', which: 9 }));") 'nothing happens
Await WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').dispatchEvent(New KeyboardEvent('keypress', { keyCode: 'Tab', which: 9 }));") 'nothing happens
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.